# How to filter data from array using the id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a API and that api give me list of users detail, I want to filter the details of user according to logged in user id, How can i filter data using specific id from array.

Any solution appreciated...!

Comment: what is your real issue? Have you tried anything? if, yes please provide the codes.

Comment: No, i just find the way before i try. Because someone is working on API and he will give me all the users detail

Comment: Without seeing your API response, it is difficult to provide us any solutions.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lb5q7py0/1/
use jquery filter for better performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tough to make a suggestion without more information, but for example, if your data looks like `apiData` below, then you could simply make a new array and push all the items with the chosen `userId` property value to it:

```js
const apiData = [
  { userId: 1, favoriteColor: "blue" },
  { userId: 2, favoriteColor: "yellow" },
  { userId: 1, favoriteFood: "pasta" },
  { userId: 2, favoriteFood: "cookies" },
];

const filteredData = [];
apiData.forEach(function(item){
  if(item.userId == 1){
    filteredData.push(item);
  }
});

console.log(filteredData);
```

Comment: Try something like `var result = apiData.filter(x => x.userId == 1);`

Answer (score 2):

I am considering you are getting array of objects.
suppose you have array a. then

```
for (var i =0;i<a.length,a++){
  if(a[i].user_id == <specific user_id>){
   // your code
   break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanku for this solution, it works with my dummy data

Comment: You should add a break-statement if the specific user id has been found. There is no reason to continue searching the array if the user id has been found.

Comment: @RobinSingh what about one liner solution - `var result = a.filter(x => x.user_id == <specific user_id>);`

Answer (score 0):

1. include underscore.js in your app .

```
._filter(x => x.apiResopnseId == yourId); //return filtered users detail
```

Comment: You don't have to use underscore to filter. there is filter function in JS https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/filter